# dllexport unexpectedly doesn't cause linker error in referencing project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllimport, dllexport

I've run across some behavior that, from my understanding, should cause a linker error.

I have two C++ projects *MyLib* and *MyLibTests*. *MyLib* is a windows dll project. In that project is a header file *Declspec.h*

```
// Declspec.h
#pragma once
#define NATIVE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#define NATIVE_API_CALL __cdecl
```

which is used to annotate functions that have to be exported (in order to test them).

Now there are several header files that declare functions, for example *GUID.h* (I cut out the unnecessary parts):

```
// GUID.h
NATIVE_API GUID newGuid();
```

and their associated source files, for example *GUID.cpp*:

```
// GUID.cpp
GUID newGuid()
{
    GUID g;
    (void)CoCreateGuid(&g);
    return g;
}
```

*MyLib* builds *GUID.cpp* and everything is fine so far. Now *MyLibTests* references the dll and calls the `newGuid()` function. To do this, the very same *GUID.h* is included in *MyLibTests*. The code compiles and it looks like it runs properly. This is the point I don't understand. By including *GUID.h*, we transitively include *Declspec.h* which resolves the `NATIVE_API` macro to `__declspec(dllexport)`, meaning the function should be exported again (which in itself is wrong already). I assumed that `dllexport` requires a definition to be available within one of the translation units (namely *GUID.cpp* here) in order to allow export. But since *GUID.cpp* is **not** built as part of the *MyLibTests* project I would expect a linker error instead of a successful build.

The way I know it, is for *Declspec.h* to look like this:

```
// Declspec.h
#ifdef SOME_PROJECT_DEPENDEND_MACRO
#   define NATIVE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define NATIVE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and `SOME_PROJECT_DEPENDEND_MACRO` beeing a macro declared in the project file of the project that provides the function. This way, all includes inside the defining project get the `dllexport` signature, while all referencing projects include the header files with a `dllimport` signature (and therefore don't look for a definition inside their own translation units).

Why do both projects compile (and run) successfully despite all functions beeing always `dllexport`ed in both projects?

Comment: dllexport provides a hint to the linker, tells it that it needs to put the function declaration into the project's import library.  But since you don't actually build a library it just shrugs it off.  If you forget to link the real import library, the one generated by the DLL project, then you'll get linker errors.

Comment: @HansPassant so because *MyLibTests* is an executable it just discards the `__declspec(dllexport)` part and I don't get a linker error because I'm linking against the import library which contains the definition for my function (which is then forwarded to the dll at runtime)?

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers have an option to only create the preprocessed file, instead of actually compiling & creating an object file.

For e.g. Visual Studio compiler has the [/E option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/e-preprocess-to-stdout?view=vs-2019). You can then check the preprocessed file to see what `NATIVE_API` is actually getting pre-processed to in your test source files. When combined with other options, you can get the preprocessor output written to a file & check it. Maybe the definition is coming from somewhere else as compared to where you are expecting it from.

Comment: I've just verified it and it really resolves to a `dllexport` so there is no hidden macro redefinition.